# Is it an overconstrained rostering problem not addressed properly?

Tags: java, drools, scheduling, optaplanner, rostering

I'm trying to  implement a Shift Scheduling system based on Nurse Rostering example. Unfortunately, i cannot get it right. Apparently,seems that it is an overconstrained problem which needs special attention and detailed custom moves (i have not developed any custom move,yet) and/or tweaking of weights and maybe redefinition of some constraints.
I am not sure and i can't find a way out.
Here are the problem details:

1. 365 days (or at least 180 days)
2. Each day has 2 shifts Day and Night
3. 25 pharmacies (with no special skills)  divided in 2 groups:

   - Group A contains zone1 Pharmacies
   - Group B contains zone2 Pharmacies
4. 3 Pharmacies have the same address (members of the same group B) but are considered independent.

### Constraints

1. One shift per day for employees **Hard constraint**
2. Min and Max number of Day Shifts,
   Night Shifts and Total Assignments fairly distributed.**Soft Constraint**.
3. Alternate shift pattern(D-N or N-D) ->unwanted patterns (N-N) and (D-D) **Hard constraint**
4. minimum free days between workdays **Soft Constraint**
5. no consecutive workdays  **Hard constraint**
6. Zone coverage: DAY and NIGHT shifts should be assigned to 1 pharmacy from each zone .**Soft Constraint**
7. For same address employees: No 2 assignments in the same day **Hard constraint**,time between them = 3 days (**Hard constraint** but if needed for problem relaxation could be **Soft constraint**)

From input file:dataset.xml

```
<Contract ID="0"><Description>fulltime</Description>
<SingleAssignmentPerDay weight="1">true</SingleAssignmentPerDay><MaxNumAssignments on="1" weight="1">13</MaxNumAssignments><MinNumAssignments on="1" weight="1">11</MinNumAssignments><MaxNumDayAssignments on="1" weight="1">7</MaxNumDayAssignments>
<MinNumDayAssignments on="1" weight="1">5</MinNumDayAssignments>
<MaxNumNightAssignments on="1" weight="1">7</MaxNumNightAssignments>
<MinNumNightAssignments on="1" weight="1">5</MinNumNightAssignments>
<MaxConsecutiveWorkingDays on="1" weight="1">1</MaxConsecutiveWorkingDays><MinConsecutiveWorkingDays on="0" weight="1">1</MinConsecutiveWorkingDays> <MaxConsecutiveFreeDays on="1" weight="1">12</MaxConsecutiveFreeDays>
<MinConsecutiveFreeDays on="1" weight="4">5</MinConsecutiveFreeDays>
<UnwantedPatterns>
<Pattern>0</Pattern>
<Pattern>1</Pattern>
</UnwantedPatterns> 
</Contract>  
Where Pattern{0,1}={(DAY,DAY),(NIGHT,NIGHT)}`
```

**RULES**

```
    rule "oneShiftPerDay"
dialect "mvel"
    when
        $leftAssignment : ShiftAssignment($leftId : id, $pharmacy : pharmacy, $shiftDate : shiftDate, pharmacy != null)
        $rightAssignment : ShiftAssignment(pharmacy == $pharmacy, shiftDate == $shiftDate, id > $leftId)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch( kcontext, -10);
        
end

rule "insertPharmacyAssignmentTotal"
       salience 2 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
dialect "mvel"
    when
    MinMaxContractLine(contractLineType == ContractLineType.TOTAL_ASSIGNMENTS, enabled == true,$contract : contract)
    $pharmacy : Pharmacy(contract == $contract)
    $assignmentTotal : Number() from accumulate(
            $assignment : ShiftAssignment(pharmacy == $pharmacy,$sdi1:shiftDateDayIndex),
            count($assignment)
            )
     
    then
    
       insertLogical(new PharmacyAssignmentTotal($pharmacy, $assignmentTotal.intValue()));
           
end




  rule "insertPharmacyWorkSequence"
        salience 1 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentStart(
            $pharmacy : pharmacy,
            $firstDayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex
        )

        PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentEnd(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy,
            shiftDateDayIndex >= $firstDayIndex,
            $lastDayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex
        )

        // There are no free days between the first and last day
        not PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentEnd(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy,
            shiftDateDayIndex >= $firstDayIndex && < $lastDayIndex
        )
    then
        insertLogical(new PharmacyWorkSequence($pharmacy, $firstDayIndex, $lastDayIndex));
end


rule "insertFirstPharmacyFreeSequence"
        salience 1 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentStart(
            $pharmacy : pharmacy,
            $lastDayIndexPlusOne : shiftDateDayIndex
        )

        // There are no working days before the first day
        not PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentEnd(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy,
            shiftDateDayIndex < $lastDayIndexPlusOne
        )
        PharmacyRosterInfo(firstShiftDateDayIndex < $lastDayIndexPlusOne, $firstDayIndex : firstShiftDateDayIndex)
    then
        insertLogical(new PharmacyFreeSequence($pharmacy, $firstDayIndex, $lastDayIndexPlusOne - 1));
end

rule "insertLastPharmacyFreeSequence"
        salience 1 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentEnd(
            $pharmacy : pharmacy,
            $firstDayIndexMinusOne : shiftDateDayIndex
        )

        // There are no working days after the last day
        not PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentStart(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy,
            shiftDateDayIndex > $firstDayIndexMinusOne
        )
       PharmacyRosterInfo(lastShiftDateDayIndex > $firstDayIndexMinusOne, $lastDayIndex : lastShiftDateDayIndex)
    then
        insertLogical(new PharmacyFreeSequence($pharmacy, $firstDayIndexMinusOne + 1, $lastDayIndex));
end
rule "insertEntirePharmacyFreeSequence"
        salience 1 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        $pharmacy : Pharmacy()
        // There are no working days after the last day
        not PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentStart(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy
        )
        PharmacyRosterInfo($firstDayIndex : firstShiftDateDayIndex, $lastDayIndex : lastShiftDateDayIndex)
    then
        insertLogical(new PharmacyFreeSequence($pharmacy, $firstDayIndex, $lastDayIndex));
end
rule "insertPharmacyFreeSequence"
        salience 1 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentEnd(
            $pharmacy : pharmacy,
            $firstDayIndexMinusOne : shiftDateDayIndex
        )

        PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentStart(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy,
            shiftDateDayIndex > $firstDayIndexMinusOne,
            $lastDayIndexPlusOne : shiftDateDayIndex
        )

        // There are no working days between the first and last day
        not PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentStart(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy,
            shiftDateDayIndex > $firstDayIndexMinusOne && < $lastDayIndexPlusOne
        )
    then
        insertLogical(new PharmacyFreeSequence($pharmacy, $firstDayIndexMinusOne + 1, $lastDayIndexPlusOne - 1));
end



rule "Minimum and Maximum total assignments"
salience 1
no-loop
    when
  
        $contractLine : MinMaxContractLine(
            contractLineType == ContractLineType.TOTAL_ASSIGNMENTS, maximumEnabled == true,
            $contract : contract, $maximumValue : maximumValue
        )
        $pharmacy: Pharmacy(contract == $contract)
          accumulate(
            $assignment : ShiftAssignment($pharmacy == pharmacy);
            $total : count($assignment)
        )
 then
   int totalInt = $total.intValue();
   if (totalInt < $contractLine.getMinimumValue()) {
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,
                    (totalInt - $contractLine.getMinimumValue()) * $contractLine.getMinimumWeight());
              helperWithMessage(drools,"minimum total ass for "+$pharmacy.getName()+" is "+$contractLine.getMinimumValue()+" > "+totalInt);       
        } else if (totalInt > $contractLine.getMaximumValue()) {
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,
                    ($contractLine.getMaximumValue() - totalInt) * $contractLine.getMaximumWeight());
           helperWithMessage(drools,"maximum total ass for "+$pharmacy.getName()+" is "+$contractLine.getMaximumValue()+" < "+totalInt);       
                          } else {
            // Workaround for https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-761
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0);      
    
        }

            
        
end
rule "Minimum and maximum number of day service assignments"
dialect "mvel"
    when
        $contractLine : MinMaxContractLine(contractLineType == ContractLineType.TOTAL_DAY_ASSIGNMENTS, enabled == true,
            $contract : contract)
  
           $pharmacy: Pharmacy(contract == $contract)
        accumulate(
            $assignment : ShiftAssignment($pharmacy == pharmacy,$shiftType:shift.getShiftType,$shiftType.toString=="DAY");
            $total : count($assignment)
        )
        
    then
        int totalInt = $total.intValue();
        if ($contractLine.isMinimumEnabled() && totalInt < $contractLine.getMinimumValue()) {
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,
                    (totalInt - $contractLine.getMinimumValue()) * $contractLine.getMinimumWeight());
        } else if ($contractLine.isMaximumEnabled() && totalInt > $contractLine.getMaximumValue()) {
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,
                    ($contractLine.getMaximumValue() - totalInt) * $contractLine.getMaximumWeight());
        } else {
            // Workaround for https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-761
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0);        
        }
end




rule "Minimum and maximum number of night service assignments"
dialect "mvel"
    when
        $contractLine : MinMaxContractLine(contractLineType == ContractLineType.TOTAL_NIGHT_ASSIGNMENTS, enabled == true,
            $contract : contract)
        $pharmacy: Pharmacy(contract == $contract)
          $total : Number() from  accumulate(
            $assignment : ShiftAssignment($pharmacy == pharmacy,$shiftType:shift.getShiftType,$shiftType.toString=="NIGHT");       
            count($assignment)
        )
        
    then
        int totalInt = $total.intValue();
        if ($contractLine.isMinimumEnabled() && totalInt < $contractLine.getMinimumValue()) {
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,
                    (totalInt - $contractLine.getMinimumValue()) * $contractLine.getMinimumWeight());
        } else if ($contractLine.isMaximumEnabled() && totalInt > $contractLine.getMaximumValue()) {
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,
                    ($contractLine.getMaximumValue() - totalInt) * $contractLine.getMaximumWeight());
        } else {
            // Workaround for https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-761
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0); helper(drools);
        }
end



rule "minimumConsecutiveFreeDays"
    when
        $contractLine : MinMaxContractLine(
            contractLineType == ContractLineType.CONSECUTIVE_FREE_DAYS, minimumEnabled == true,
            $contract : contract, $minimumValue : minimumValue
        )
        $pharmacy : Pharmacy(contract == $contract)

        $pharmacyFreeSequence : PharmacyFreeSequence(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy,
            dayLength < $minimumValue,
            $dayLength : dayLength
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,($dayLength-$minimumValue )* $contractLine.getMinimumWeight()); 
   end

rule "maxConsecutiveWorkingDays"
when
        $contractLine : MinMaxContractLine(
            contractLineType == ContractLineType.CONSECUTIVE_WORKING_DAYS, maximumEnabled == true,
            $contract : contract, $maximumValue : maximumValue
        )

        PharmacyWorkSequence(
            getPharmacy().getContract() == $contract,
            dayLength > $maximumValue,
            $dayLength : dayLength
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, ($maximumValue - $dayLength) * $contractLine.getMaximumWeight());
end




rule "maximumConsecutiveFreeDays"
    when
        $contractLine : MinMaxContractLine(
            contractLineType == ContractLineType.CONSECUTIVE_FREE_DAYS, maximumEnabled == true,
            $contract : contract, $maximumValue : maximumValue
        )
        $pharmacy : Pharmacy(contract == $contract)

        $pharmacyFreeSequence : PharmacyFreeSequence(
            pharmacy == $pharmacy,
            dayLength > $maximumValue,
            $dayLength : dayLength
        )
    then
     scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,($maximumValue - $dayLength )* $contractLine.getMaximumWeight()); helper(drools);
end


rule "insertPharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentStart"
        salience 2 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        ShiftAssignment(
            $pharmacy : pharmacy, pharmacy != null,
            $dayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex,
            $shiftDate : shiftDate
        )
        // The first day has no working day before it
        not ShiftAssignment(pharmacy == $pharmacy, shiftDateDayIndex == ($dayIndex - 1))
    then
        insertLogical(new PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentStart($pharmacy, $shiftDate));
end
rule "insertPharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentEnd"
        salience 2 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        ShiftAssignment(
            $pharmacy : pharmacy, pharmacy != null,
            $dayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex,
            $shiftDate : shiftDate
        )
        // The last day has no working day after it
        not ShiftAssignment(pharmacy == $pharmacy, shiftDateDayIndex == ($dayIndex + 1))
    then
       insertLogical(new PharmacyConsecutiveAssignmentEnd($pharmacy, $shiftDate));
end



rule "sameAddress4DaysFree"
dialect "mvel"
    when
    $leftAssignment : ShiftAssignment($leftPharmacy : pharmacy,$leftCode:pharmacy.getCode, $ldi : shiftDate.dayIndex, $leftAddress:pharmacy.getAddress(), pharmacy != null)
    ShiftAssignment($rightPharmacy:pharmacy,pharmacy.getAddress()==$leftAddress,$rightPharmacy.getCode()!=$leftCode,$sdi:shiftDateDayIndex,$sdi == $ldi,pharmacy != null)
    or ShiftAssignment($rightPharmacy:pharmacy,$rightPharmacy.getAddress()==$leftAddress,$rightPharmacy.getCode()!=$leftCode,$sdi:shiftDateDayIndex,$sdi == $ldi+1,pharmacy != null)
    or ShiftAssignment($rightPharmacy:pharmacy,$rightPharmacy.getAddress()==$leftAddress,$rightPharmacy.getCode()!=$leftCode,$sdi:shiftDateDayIndex,$sdi == $ldi+2,pharmacy != null)
   or ShiftAssignment($rightPharmacy:pharmacy,$rightPharmacy.getAddress()==$leftAddress,$rightPharmacy.getCode()!=$leftCode,$sdi:shiftDateDayIndex,$sdi == $ldi+3,pharmacy != null)
   or ShiftAssignment($rightPharmacy:pharmacy,$rightPharmacy.getAddress()==$leftAddress,$rightPharmacy.getCode()!=$leftCode,$sdi:shiftDateDayIndex,$sdi == $ldi+4,pharmacy != null)
   
  then 

  int penalty=$sdi-$ldi;
      scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch( kcontext, -4/penalty);
end

rule "alternateShiftTypes"

when
        $contractLine : MinMaxContractLine(
            contractLineType == ContractLineType.CONSECUTIVE_SAME_SHIFT_TYPE, maximumEnabled == true,
            $contract : contract, $maximumValue : maximumValue
        )
        
           ShiftAssignment($pharmacy : pharmacy, $pharmacy != null,$shiftDate1:shiftDate,$dayIndex1:shiftDateDayIndex,$ShiftType1:shiftType, contract == $contract)
           ShiftAssignment($pharmacy== pharmacy,$dayIndex2:shiftDateDayIndex,$shiftDate2:shiftDate,$dayIndex2>$dayIndex1,$ShiftType2:shiftType
           ,$ShiftType2!=$ShiftType1)
               not  ShiftAssignment($pharmacy== pharmacy,$dayIndex3:shiftDateDayIndex,$dayIndex3>$dayIndex1,
          $dayIndex3<$dayIndex2)
   then
      scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch( kcontext, 1);
  end

rule "ZoneCoverage"
when
$leftAssignment : ShiftAssignment($leftId :id, $leftPharmacy : pharmacy,$leftCode:pharmacy.code, $leftShiftDate : shiftDate, $leftCentral:pharmacy.getCentral, pharmacy != null)
    $rightAssignment : ShiftAssignment(id > $leftId, $rightPharmacy : pharmacy,$rightPharmacy !=$leftPharmacy,  shiftDate == $leftShiftDate,$leftCentral==pharmacy.getCentral, pharmacy != null)
    then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);        
end

rule "evenlyDistributeTotalAssignments"
dialect "mvel"

when 
$sum:  Number() from 
accumulate(PharmacyAssignmentTotal($pharmacy:pharmacy,$assignmentTotal:total),sum($assignmentTotal)) 
    $sumSquared:Number() from accumulate(PharmacyAssignmentTotal($assignmentTotal:total),sum(squaredValue($assignmentTotal))
        )  
     then
```

getFairnessValue($sum.intValue(),$sumSquared.intValue()));
scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1*getFairnessValue($sum.intValue(),$sumSquared.intValue()));
end

```
rule "unwantedPatternShiftType2DaysPattern"

    when
        $pattern : ShiftType2DaysPattern(
            $dayIndex0ShiftType : dayIndex0ShiftType,
            $dayIndex1ShiftType : dayIndex1ShiftType
        )
        PatternContractLine(
            pattern == $pattern, $contract : contract
        )


        ShiftAssignment(
            shiftType == $dayIndex0ShiftType,
            contract == $contract,
            $pharmacy : pharmacy, $firstDayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex
        )
      
       ShiftAssignment(shiftType == $dayIndex1ShiftType,pharmacy == $pharmacy,
           $dayIndex2:shiftDateDayIndex,$dayIndex2 > $firstDayIndex )
       not ShiftAssignment($pharmacy== pharmacy,$dayIndex3:shiftDateDayIndex,$dayIndex3>$firstDayIndex,
          $dayIndex3<$dayIndex2)
    
        
    then
         scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end
```

[image: Benchmark]

No matter what i do,i get no good solutions.Could be a conflict betweeen the 2 constraints freesequence and the freedays of the same address pharmacies?
Performance is terrible and i see that the solver gets stuck in local minima.
Any ideas?

Comment: TLDR, but it looks like it's still improving the hard score after 20 minutes, so check your score calculation speed (last log line, or in benchmarker performance graph): is it above 10k? or at least above 1k?

Comment: Commenting out/in constraints can help to determine which constraints are causing this behavior. Maybe one if them is penalizing too much. For example if there needs to be 3 days between two assignments, but it penalizes if there are 4. Or maybe you have a "score trap".